# How to match to a shell variable in awk?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, gawk

I am trying to match a shell variable with the second column separated by commas.
So I've set ***$INOW*** to **ls** and the command looks like this

```
awk -F"," '$2 == $INOW {print "yeah it's there"}' commands.csv
```

I have tried putting quotes around $INOW. no difference. How do i make a match to the shell variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant use shell variables directly in `awk`. Rather you can create an awk variable using `-v`

**Example**

```
$ a_variable=hello
$ awk -v var="$a_variable" "{print var}"
hello
```

So in your case you can write like,

```
$ awk -F"," -v inow="$INOW" '$2 == inow {print "yeah its there"}' commands.csv
```

Comment: I get it, I tried it but it is not working for some reason.  It's showing the incomplete command thing. i.e after i issue that your command with makes sense to me this comes up.

Comment: $ awk -F"," -v inow="$INOW" '$2 == inow {print "yeah it's there"}' commands.csv then in the next lines
 
>
 >

Comment: @HrishikeshBarman You have a syntax error. there is ans extra `'` in the command you have written. either remove it or escape it

Comment: working now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"," '{if($2 == '$INOW') {print "yeah its there"}else{print "nope"}}' commands.csv
```

Comment: $INOW doesn't seem to be evaluated. because the else part is getting evaluated but the if part is not. $INOW is truthy.